# How to get navigation parameter before re-render the page

Tags: react-native

I'm using react navigation to navigate between pages. I have 2 pages. Let's call them A and B. I have some cards on page A and has touchable opacities on cards to navigate to page B with an id (using this id for getting data from the server).

On first navigation from A to B everything works well. But when i go back to page A from sidemenu and select another card (i mean send another id as parameter to page B) its show me same page with first navigate. I figured out navigation parameter changes after the render.

i tried that lifecycle;

```
export class TanksContent extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
super(props);
 this.state = {
  isLoading:true,
  tanks:[],
 }   
}

componentDidMount(){
 this.getData();
}

componentWillUnmount(){
 this.setState({
  isLoading: true
 });
}

componentWillUpdate(){
 this.getData();
}

getData(){
 //fetching data on here from server and set state for loading and data.
}

render(){
 if(this.state.isLoading){
  return(
    <View style={{flex: 1, padding: 20}}>
      <ActivityIndicator/>
    </View>
  )
 } 
return(
 // screen
)
```

Its refreshing the page again and again... So its not working well. How could i stop rendering until parameter has changed? (its possible to user choose the same parameter again)

Comment: You can use componentDidUpdate() to update, and you can insert conditions inside to run them when the conditions are right.

Answer (score 0):

I solved that problem.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
 if(this.props.id!==this.state.id){
  this.setState({ 
    id:  this.props.id,
    isLoading: true
  });
  this.getData();
 }
}
```

with that function. if someone need help about that just comment and i will do my best for you.